# Twilio, connect PLAY to conference

Tags: twilio

Is it possible to Play in a Conference between 2 people by adding a new call to that conference which Plays. Will there be an inherent "lag" when that call joins because of the minimum 2 way network trip that happens. Is it possible to cut that down to 1 way by pushing TwiML to Twilio instead of having Twilio pull it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

There isn't a way to have Twilio store the TwiML, but there are strategies that can help reduce the lag.

One of the biggest things you can do when using the `<Play>` verb is to make sure that you are returning proper caching headers for both your TwiML and the audio file you are planing.  Twilio is a well-behaved HTTP client and will honor those headers.

- https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/your_response
- https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play#hints
- https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/how-can-i-change-the-cache-behavior-of-audio-files

Hope that helps